# Calculating the average number of colored balls drawn at random

Tags: probability

In my scenario, let's say I have a bag with a total of $64$ colored balls. $6$ are red, and $58$ are blue. If I draw half of the balls from the bag ($32$), without replacing them, how would I calculate the average number of red balls that would be drawn? In other words, if I were to repeat this draw many times, how many reds on an average per draw would I see?

My naive (and probably wrong!) assumption would be it's the probability of picking a red ($\frac{6}{64}$) multiplied by the number of reds ($6$), so ($\frac{36}{64} = 0.5625$)...but I have no idea if that's even remotely right.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well, the answer has to be the same as the average number of red balls you $\textit {didn't}$ pick, so...

Comment: Consider the average number of blue balls drawn. Your method says take the probability of drawing blue ($58/64$) times the number of blues ($58$), so $58^2/64=52.5625$ blue balls on average out of $32$ balls drawn—something is wrong with the method.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the average number of blue balls drawn. Your method says take the probability of drawing blue ($58/64$) times the number of blues ($58$), so $58^2/64=52.5625$ blue balls on average out of $32$ balls drawn—something is wrong with the method.

A correct method that’s relatively easy to apply to problems like this is to use the property of *linearity of expectation.* It says (among other things) that the expectation of a sum of random variables is the sum of their expectations. A useful thing about this property is that it is true even when the random variables are not independent.

To turn your problem into a sum of random variables, we lay out the balls we pick in a row of spots numbered from $1$ to $32.$
Let $X_k=1$ if the ball in spot number $k$ is red, $X_k=0$ otherwise. 
Then the number of red balls picked is just the sum
$$X=X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{32}.\tag1$$

But if you just look at one of the spots, say spot number $k,$ the probability that the ball there is red instead of blue is $6/64.$
So the expected number of red balls in that spot is $E(X_k)=6/64.$

So when we take the expected value on each side of Equation $(1)$ we have a sum of $32$ copies of $6/64$ on the right side,
which add up to $32\times 6/64 = 3.$ That’s the answer.

This method is just as easy to apply if we chose $23$ balls instead of $32.$

Note that your idea of multiplying $6/64$ by something was a good one in this case; the key is to multiply by the correct number.

Comment: nice and clear explanation

Comment: Thanks David, that's an excellent and clear explanation, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you left behind $32$ balls, so by symmetry the mean number of red balls you chose must be the same as the mean number of red balls you didn't choose.  Since they sum to $6$ the answer must be $3$.

Maybe worth doing the computation by hand...if, say, you had chosen $31$ balls instead of $32$ you'd have to do it out.  The probability that you choose exactly $i$ red balls is $$\binom 6i\times \binom {58}{32-i}\Big / \binom {64}{32}$$  With mechanical help we see that the probabilities of getting exactly $0,\cdots, 6$ red balls are (respectively):

$$0.012086691,0.085949801,0.23789677,0.328133476,0.23789677,0.085949801,0.012086691$$

And it's now easy to confirm that the mean is $3$.  Note that $p_i=p_{6-i}$, which is another expression of the symmetry involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). Since expected value is linear, we can say that the expected number of red balls is just the expected number of red balls you pick up with one draw, $\frac{6}{64}$, multiplied by the number of draws $32$, which is just $3$.